# Double slider Sign in/up Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет. Начал вникать в react, но никак не пойму, что не так с формой.

Пишу форму авторизации, двойную, но при инициализации возникает ошибка:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
```

Подскажите, что не так?

Как то не так определяю функцию, ток не пойму ,что не так.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
const signInButton = document.getElementById('signIn');
const container = document.getElementById('container');

signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add("right-panel-active");
});

signInButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span {
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #FF4B2B;
    background-color: #FF4B2B;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
}

button:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button.ghost {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

form {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

input {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 
            0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.form-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {
    0%, 49.99% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    50%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}

.overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay {
    background: #FF416C;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FF4B2B, #FF416C);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF4B2B, #FF416C);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-right {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
    transform: translateX(20%);
}

.social-container {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
}

footer p {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

footer i {
    color: red;
}

footer a {
    color: #3c97bf;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
      <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
        <form action="#">
            <h1>Create Account</h1>
            <div class="social-container">
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>or use your email for registration</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <button>Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
        <form action="#">
            <h1>Sign in</h1>
            <div class="social-container">
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>or use your account</span>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
            <button>Sign In</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-container">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
                <p>To keep connected with us please login with your personal info</p>
                <button class="ghost"  id="signIn">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                <h1>Hello, Friend!</h1>
                <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us</p>
                <button class="ghost"  id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```